# Can I boot from external usb hdd?

Tags: boot, live-usb

I have bootable ubuntu usb and everything is working fine. Note that I can boot only from usb or cd/dvd.

Now I want to install new programs, edit my own files etc... So I thought that the best solution would be to

- boot fom my external (160GB WD) or
- have root directory automatically mounted to the external hdd when booting from usb

Is any from above possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently running my Acer Aspire 5440 laptop off of an external WD Passport 500gb hard drive, and have been for a year now. I haven't had any issues with it, other than the occasional disconnect issue. I don't see any performance problems with it, as long as the computer has a good set of hardware, RAM, video, processor, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All are possible !
The only thing that will bother you is the performance issues that will be very poor due to USB 2.0 input - output (read - wright) performance limitations.

You should also check for some other problems you may encounter https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Can+I+boot+from+external+usb+hdd